# PHP extract the part of the document which is the most significant concerning the search words

Tags: php, mysql, string, full-text-search

**I modified the text to be clearer.**

This excerpt below is from a 500 page book. The goal is to extract the part of the document which is the most significant concerning the search words and to display it. I had thought of finding the position of each word in the text with STRIPOS in PHP, and finding the part in the text which contains the most positions of the search terms, which would give, say, a position in the text between the 1000th and 1400th character, and then I could extract the text.

So I would get a series of positions for each word searched.

institut: 3,8,5,5,67,80,90,92,165

français: 4,8,15,26,78

canadien: 12, 56, 79

ottawa: 5,8,14,45,70,82,120,140,157,200,700

The trick is to find the correspondence between these series to find the most significant extract. I don't know if this is a good way to go.

The extract string would be around 400 characters in total and would be like this:

> le président de l'**Institut** C.-F., qui
> fait partie de la délégation **canadienne** à la conférence postale
> internationale de Buenos-Aires, a été samedi soir agréablement surpris
> par ses amis de l'**Institut**. Une surprise à l'**Institut**
> **canadien**.Les membres de l'**Institut**-**Canadien** **Français** se sont
> réunis samedi

I have no clue where to start even if I did my research on the web, found nothing about it. At least I would need a clue to start the coding.

Thanks,
Andy

Comment: AFAIK, MySQL doesn't provide any way to tell you where the matches are in the string. It just returns a score telling you how good the match is.

Comment: This sounds like a job for a natural language processing library, once you've found the matches in the DB using FTS.

Comment: @Barmar Since it's a specialise database on a single subject, most of the time  IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE it gives no result: «The search result is empty because the word “MySQL” is present in at least 50% of the rows, and so is effectively treated as a stopword.»

Comment: You need to provide more specific searches. Searching for a word that appears in most documents isn't very useful.

Comment: That's a separate problem from highlighting the words.

Comment: @Barmar My question wasn't precise enough, I changed it for: «I would like to extract part of string with of the most concentrated match found». Afterwards, highlighting is not a problem.

Comment: What you're trying to do is clear. \And I'm still saying you need a NLP library, since you also appear to want to handle different spellings, like "canadienne` and "Canadien".

Comment: No simple string operations can do that.

Comment: I use google to translate from french to english...This excerpt above is from a 500 page book. The goal is to extract the part of the document which is the most significant concerning the search words and to display it.

I had thought of finding the position of each word in the text with STRIPOS in PHP, and finding the small group in the text which contains the most position of the search terms, which would give, say, a position in the text between the 1000th and 1400th character, and then I could extract the text. To complicated for me.

Comment: I don't understand how the gap between positions can be shorter than the length of the word (unless positions are word boundaries and not 'characters'), nor how we can have repeats of the same position.